# Pandas: substitute NA's with shadow values obtained from contemporary non missing values in other column

Tags: pandas

Suppose I have the following prices, for asset X:

```
2004              NaN
2005              NaN
2006    246313.490770
2007    245557.678822
2008              NaN
2009              NaN
2010    246221.051892
```

The values of X are missing for some of the years.

and I also have a price for a comparable asset, asset Y (asset Y never has NaN prices):

```
2004    249008.038563
2005    248558.125114
2006    249644.313926
2007    249381.243924
2008    248739.371177
2009    249514.093672
2010    251120.103454
```

For every NaN in the price of asset X (top matrix), I would like to replace that NaN by the last non NaN value of asset X multiplied by the growth rate of Y (botom matrix) in the intermediate years.

So for example the substitution value in 2009 would be:

```
245557.678822/249381.243924*249514.093672
```

(value for 2007 of X  times the growth rate of Y between 2007 and 2009)

the values for 2004 and 2005 would remain NaN's though.

I can code this using ugly nested loops but I was wondering if there was an elegant two liners in pandas to do that (I have a dataframe with several columns X.1, X.2,... with scattered missing values and a column Y with no missing values)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need first divide by [`div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.div.html) both columns, then forward fill `NaN` by [`ffill`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.Series.ffill.html) and last multiplicate by [`mul`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mul.html):

```
print (X)
               col1
2004            NaN
2005            NaN
2006  246313.490770
2007  245557.678822
2008            NaN
2009            NaN
2010  246221.051892

print (Y)
               col1
2004  249008.038563
2005  248558.125114
2006  249644.313926
2007  249381.243924
2008  248739.371177
2009  249514.093672
2010  251120.103454
```

```
print (X.col1.div(Y.col1))
2004         NaN
2005         NaN
2006    0.986658
2007    0.984668
2008         NaN
2009         NaN
2010    0.980491
Name: col1, dtype: float64

print (X.col1.div(Y.col1).ffill())
2004         NaN
2005         NaN
2006    0.986658
2007    0.984668
2008    0.984668
2009    0.984668
2010    0.980491
Name: col1, dtype: float64

X['new'] = (X.col1.div(Y.col1).ffill().mul(Y.col1))

print (X)
               col1            new
2004            NaN            NaN
2005            NaN            NaN
2006  246313.490770  246313.490770
2007  245557.678822  245557.678822
2008            NaN  244925.647401
2009            NaN  245688.491690
2010  246221.051892  246221.051892

print (245557.678822/249381.243924*249514.093672)
245688.4916900315
```

Comment: Yes, I checked on other columns and this is exactly *it*! Thanks!